# Getting the contents of a container from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There is a code. I do not need to get the whole page, but only container with ID conta (# conta)

```
$.ajax({
        url: fileID
    }).success(function (data) {
        $('.portfolio-detail').addClass('open-box');
        $('.portfolio-detail').html(data);
        $('.portfolio-detail').removeClass('closed-box');

        $('.close-detail').click(function () {
            $('.portfolio-detail').addClass('closed-box');
            $('.portfolio-detail').removeClass('open-box');
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#portfolio').offset().top - 68
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.portfolio-detail').html('');
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your Question is not clear, please ask with right explanation\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add only *#conta* who is in *data variable*, use this :

```
$('.portfolio-detail').html($(data).find("#conta").html());
```

Or with *append function* :

```
$('.portfolio-detail').append($(data).find("#conta"));
```

Comment: well, this is what I need!